# How to migrate from IdentityServer3 to Duende IdentityServer6?

Tags: upgrade, identityserver3, migrate, duende-identity-server

I have an IdentityServer3 used by multiple applications. The clients, scopes, flows, urls etc., of the IdentityServer3 are persisted in an MS SQL Server. I want to upgrade the IdentityServer3 to Duende IdentityServer6 as the support for the former is going to end (even IdentityServer4 is not supported anymore). Could you advise the best possible way to migrate to Duende IdentityServer6, please?

Are there any straight-forward commands which will do the migration automatically?

If not, creating a brand-new Duende IdentityServer6 solution and copying the existing logic from the old IdentityServer3 solution is the only way?

Can we re-use the same MS SQL Server for the migrated Duende IdentityServer6 as well?

Comment: I would create a new project, because there's so much that has changed in ASP.NET Core and IdentityServer, so so think its a good to get a fresh start. the user database you can still be using.  Some of the other temporary tables might have changed, so I would compare the databases if I were you.